# adding a xib in ios cocoa touch framework leads to code signing issues

Tags: ios, iphone

I have made a cocoa touch framework and I have added a UIViewController with nib to it to be consumed by the main project. I then embedded this framework to the main project. I could invoke the view controller and use the xib successfully in the main project in a simulator. But as soon as I try running on a provisioned device, I get the following error,

```
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fznlaigwccdaircejxtqwvegxave/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.framework:
code object is not signed at all
```

In subcomponent: `/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fznlaigwccdaircejxtqwvegxave/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyFramework.framework/TestViewController.nib`

```
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried the following to resolve this,

**1)** remove the `xibs` from the build phase and add them in a copy files phase with "`code-sign on copy`" checked. This eliminates the error but when I try to invoke the view controller, I would get a run time exception saying

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EC8E23CB-D7AE-4185-8B7A-1AAB24669027/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework> (not yet loaded)' with name 'TestViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
```

It seems to be that the compiled `.nib` needs to be code signed manually using a build script.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this? i guess I am missing something

Thanks,
Harikant

Answer (score 0):

Such error can occur when you rename some files outside XCode.

-> just remove the files from your project (Right Click - Delete and "Remove Reference")

->You re-import the files in your project and everything will be ok !

or Remove .xib if you used it.

```
*NSArray nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```